# string cursors/markers in C++ strings

Tags: c++, c++11

I am working with some big (megabytes) strings, and I need to modify them by inserting and removing characters at different locations.

To make it more efficient, instead of searching insertion/deletion points every time, I would like to have "cursors" or "tags" which are still valid if text is inserted (i.e. they are moved accordingly), and are still valid if the removed text is not "enclosing" the cursor position (i.e. a cursor becomes invalid only if it was in the removed substring, other cursors are moved accordingly).

I do not need to operate on the string concurrently, but insertion/deletion operations happen always one at time.

Do you know how this can be done with standard C++, boost or a portable, lightweight library?

Comment: You are describing a linked list.

Comment: No, you're just thinking about implementing it with linked list ;)

Comment: A pure linked list will not be too efficient, with the two pointers worth of overhead per character, but you can have a linked list of chunks of some usable size, and combine it with the John's idea of keeping a set of markers. So when you modify a chunk, you only need to update markers pointing to that chunk. Or you can have a linked list of things, each keeping *either* a chunk of text *or* a cursor pointing to that place. When you move a cursor to a new place, you possibly break up the chunk it falls in, and/or glue together the two chunks it was between.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the number of insertion points will be relatively small, why not just keep a list (or array) of your insertion points, ordered by and including their offset into the data string.

Then, any time you insert/remove some text, simply pass through that list and adjust any insertion points that are past the offset of the modification, either up or down by the size of the insertion/removal.

Of course, you'd have to decide what it meant to have a modification "hit" one of your insertion points (e.g. what to do if a deleted range includes one or more insertion points), but that'd depend on what you're trying to maintain those markers for.

Comment: Thanks for this idea. But I'll wait a bit, because I posted the question exactly to avoid reinventing the wheel :) So I'll wait to see if someone comes up with an existing solution.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can use special keywords in your text, which you match and replace using regular expressions (regex): http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/regex/

Be careful which keywords you use, because they could potentially occur naturally in the string.

Comment: This was my original thought, but string content is random and I can't really rely on this (I'd have to escape things).